# How to access variables inside a list of dictionaries?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have the following dataset. Due to the size, I'm showing only the first record of the `data1[0]`.

```py
{'person': "Jane", 'metadata': {'lat': -1.1818, 'lon': -1.8282, 'id': 28822}}
```

`data1` is a list type and I tried to obtain all the values for `'lat'` and `'lon'` using `data1['lat', 'lon']`. Any ideas on how could I access all `lat` and `lon` from the `data1` list.

Comment: I think you would need ```data[i]["metadata"]["lat"]``` for lat and similarly for longitude, where i is the variable you're using to go through the records.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Your list:

```
data1 = [{'person': "Jane", 'metadata':{'lat':-1.1818, 'lon': -1.8282, 'id':28822 }}]
```

```
list(data1[0]['metadata'].values())[:2]
```

output:

```
[-1.1818, -1.8282]
```

First value is lat, second value lon. You could easily create a dataframe for all your data using this slice.

`EDIT`:  Going 1 step further and creating a dataframe for those coordinates:

First, I am assuming you have a list of dictionaries structured as below:

```
data1 = [{'person': "Jane",   'metadata': {'lat': -1.1818, 'lon': -1.8282, 'id': 28822}},
         {'person': "John",   'metadata': {'lat': -1.0973, 'lon': -2.0012, 'id': 29823}},
         {'person': "Paul",   'metadata': {'lat': -1.3264, 'lon': -1.9531, 'id': 27824}},
         {'person': "Ringo",  'metadata': {'lat': -1.1493, 'lon': -1.8824, 'id': 29025}},
         {'person': "George", 'metadata': {'lat': -1.2001, 'lon': -1.8991, 'id': 28826}}]
```

In order to properly deal with the values you want to retrieve from each dictionary, I am also assuming you would want a dataframe format. In order to do so, you could use the following code:

```
coordinates = pd.DataFrame({'Lat'   :[data1[i]['metadata']['lat'] for i in range(len(data1))],
                            'Lon'   :[data1[i]['metadata']['lon'] for i in range(len(data1))]},
                             index = [data1[i]['person'] for i in range(len(data1))] )
```

Output:

```
coordinates
            Lat     Lon
Jane    -1.1818 -1.8282
John    -1.0973 -2.0012
Paul    -1.3264 -1.9531
Ringo   -1.1493 -1.8824
George  -1.2001 -1.8991
```

```
coordinates.info()

<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Index: 5 entries, Jane to George
Data columns (total 2 columns):
 #   Column  Non-Null Count  Dtype  
---  ------  --------------  -----  
 0   Lat     5 non-null      float64
 1   Lon     5 non-null      float64
dtypes: float64(2)
memory usage: 120.0+ bytes
```

Pay attention to the fact that the code differs a little if you want to retrieve a list of values, as shown in the first case, or just one value, as used in the dataframe construction scenario.

I believe you can work with this.

Comment: Thanks I have tired and it works fine. Is there any way to obtain all lat and lon? i tired list(data1['metadata'].values())[:2] but it returns "list indices must be integers or slices, not str" error indication

Comment: Oh, I am glad it worked for you and yes, there is a way to extract all lat and lon. Could you please post a larger version of your dataset, so I can code a proper answer?

Comment: Well, I just edited my answer and added a solution applied to the kind of data structure I assume you are using. Let me know if I got it right.